# Have nav element extend to end of page, but not over

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to have a vertical navigation bar using just HTML5 and CSS3. The desire is to have the menu appear on the left and have the rest of the page on the right. As the user scrolls down, I want the menu to move down with the user. Thus far I have the vertical menu looking the way I would like it, but I've not been able to complete the rest.  Each solution I've tried thus far either meant structuring the page in an odd way or using Javascript. Is this possible using just HTML5 and CSS3?

CSS

```
/* Menu Navigation Properties */
nav
{
    text-align: center;
    padding-right: 1.0em;
}

/* Menu container */
nav ul
{
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0.75em;
}

/* Menu item container */
nav ul li
{
    margin-top: 0em;
    margin-left: 0.15em;
    margin-right: 0.15em;
}

/* Menu item Appearance */
nav ul li a
{
    background-color: black;
    color: #D0E2F1; /* Light Blue */
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    width: 9em;
    display: block;
    border-width: 0.1em;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #dcdce9;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Menu item hovered over by user */
nav ul li a:hover
{
    background-color: #D0E2F1; /* Light Blue */
    color: black;
}

/* Current Page on the Menu */
nav ul li a.current
{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

HTML files

```
<html>
   <body>
      <nav>
         <!-- Menu Item List -->
      </nav>
      <h1>Page Title</h1>
      <!-- rest of page -->
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried position:fixed on the nav element?

Comment: I have, but that pulls it out of the page. This is worse since the page no longer flows around it, but behind it.

Comment: So you want the menu to 'float' at the top of the window with the content wrapping around it as you scroll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't wrap the rest of the page in a wrapper, you could make space for the menu with

```
body {
    padding-left: 10em;
}
```

and then fix the position of the menu and pull it back into the space left by the padding on the body

```
nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 9em; // Probably a good idea to fix the width of the menu
    margin-left: -10em;
    ...
}
```

If you can wrap the rest of the page in a wrapper, just give it enough left margin to keep it out of the way of the menu.